# Why doesn't it calculate the length of the string in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Implemented reading lines from a file and outputting to another file, but the length of each line should be displayed there, and the output is simply "lenght(text)". How to output a file?

```
main :-
    open('in.txt', read, Str),
    tell('out.txt'),
    read_file(Str,Lines),
    print_f(Lines),
    told,
    close(Str),
     nl.

read_file(Stream,[]) :-
    at_end_of_stream(Stream).

read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    read(Stream,X),
    read_file(Stream,L).

print_f([]).
print_f([H|T]):- writeln(lenght(H)), print_f(T).
```

Comment: `length` is spelled `length`, not `lenght`.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I then display the length of each line?

Comment: you are printing the term `lenght(H)` instead of computing the length of H with `atom_length(H, Len)` and then printing it with something like `writeln(Len)`

Comment: No, for some reason it gets an error. In the file I have more than 1 word in lines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you intend to write to an output stream **how many words there are on each line** of an input stream, my suggestions are as follows:

- use ISO standard predicates [open/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=open/3) and [close/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=close/1)to deal with both input and output streams.
- use [setup_and_call_cleanup/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=backward_compatibility%3Asetup_and_call_cleanup/3) (formerly [setup_call_cleanup/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setup_call_cleanup/3)) when working with streams.
- use [read_line_to_string/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_string/2) to read each line of the input stream.
- use [tokenize_atom/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=tokenize_atom/2) to break a string into a list of words.
- use [length/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2) to count the words in each list.

```
main :-
    setup_and_call_cleanup(
        open_streams(InputStream, OutputStream),
        process(InputStream, OutputStream),
        close_streams(InputStream, OutputStream) ).

open_streams(InputStream, OutputStream) :-
    open('in.txt', read, InputStream),
    open('out.txt', write, OutputStream).

process(InputStream, OutputStream) :-
    read_file(InputStream, Lines),
    print_file(OutputStream, Lines).

close_streams(InputStream, OutputStream) :-
    close(InputStream),
    close(OutputStream).

read_file(Stream, Lines) :-
    (   at_end_of_stream(Stream)
    ->  Lines = []
    ;   Lines = [Words|Rest],
        read_line_to_string(Stream, String),
        tokenize_atom(String, Words),
        read_file(Stream, Rest) ).

print_file(Stream, Lines) :-
    print_file_loop(Lines, Stream).

print_file_loop([], _).
print_file_loop([Line|Lines], Stream):-
  length(Line, Length),
  writeln(Stream, Length),
  print_file_loop(Lines, Stream).
```